# Why is it adding 2 empty lines before my extra line

Tags: powershell

I was wondering why Powershell Adds 2 empty lines before adding my values to the txt file.
I used the second line to get rid of empty lines but I would like to understand why it does it.

The if statement works as intended.

```
if($store[0] -eq "0010,4000"){
   Add-Content -Path $file -Value '0010,4000,'
   (gc $file) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | set-content $file
 }
```

Comment: What is the before-and-after contents of `$file`?

Comment: Both `Add-Content` and `Set-Content` have a `-NoNewline` switch